# Nginx converting main site to subdomain

Tags: nginx

```
server{
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name _;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name app.webdomain.ltd;

    ssl on;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ltd/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ltd/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

How would I go about making the normal https://site.ltd access /var/www/html where app.site.ltd accesses 127.0.0.1:3000

It's a reverse proxy to the port, as a client runs off the port so I need https://app.site.ltd to show what would be on the port, where as https://site.ltd to show whats in /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `server_name app.webdomain.ltd;` to `server_name app.webdomain.ltd webdomain.ltd;`

This shall start working as exactly your subdomain.

Comment: How would I set the wubdomain to a port and the real domain to a local file directory?